# Dictionary for Vietnamese to Chinese characters

Tags: dictionary, characters, reference-materials

I wanted to know if there are dictionaries (online or books) indicating the equivalent of Vietnamese syllables into Chinese characters. I do not search for Vietnamese to Chinese translations, but rather a cross-reference between Vietnamese quốc ngữ and Vietnamese chữ nôm.
Well, it's not really Chinese specific but I'm not sure where to put this question

Comment: Not specifically related to the question, but having looked for better places for this post, I can't seem to find anything it falls under within the SE network. I'd like to callout for other users to suggest where to put this post. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Wiktionary lists the vietnamese pronunciations for every chinese character they have info on (at the bottom of every page under the "Vietnamese" heading).

Other than that, the Nom Foundation database is good for converting vietnamese words to chu nom by sound, though you'll need to know enough characters to know what you're picking, which you also gave reference to yourself. It's a good resource, but limiting if you're trying to input into a computer.

Not all Chu nom are in unicode, though, so finding them can be challenging. The Nom foundation gets around it by using images, and is probably your best resource, but isn't as detailed on things such as meaning and usage (for which wiktionary has an advantage).

Answer (score 3):

http://hvdic.thivien.net/
Just type in google Hán Việt từ điển and a lot will come up. The above is the best though because it also tells you the usage of the word in literature and in compounded words

Answer (score 2):

After more googling, I didn't really find any book reference materials, but I did find really good online tools that give me exactly what I wanted:

- the handy look up tool of the Vietnamese Nôm Preservation Foundation http://www.nomfoundation.org/nom-tools/Nom-Lookup-Tool/Nom-Lookup-Tool
- the equivalent tool from a site about learning chữ nôm http://www.chunom.org/pages/ime/

chunom.org doesn't give out its reference materials, but it's maybe based on an older version of the Nom Foundation database as it returns less results sometimes.